# How can I get address wise UTXO balance for Zcash t-address

Tags: bitcoin-core, utxo, zcash

I tried to create user specific account wise zcash t-address, got the following error

zcash-cli getnewaddress "testaccount"
error code: -11
error message:
Accounts are unsupported

Is it possible to create account wise t-address?

But I have created zcash t-address successfully without account. Once I sent some amount to another t-address, remaining balance shifted to newly created t-address. Please assist me how can I get user specific address wise t-address balance?

Comment: Accounts are unsupported so this means all addresses get added to a single master account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get UTXO balance for Zcash t-address using `https://chain.so/api/` api `https://chain.so/api/v2/get_tx_unspent/ZECTEST/t2BqpZq16caHXC92LDTWg2pc8RQdmRFw5dF` in testnet.